# How to solve black screen issue on polychromatic

Tags: wingpanel

Recently I ran into a black screen issue while setting up [polychromatic](https://polychromatic.app/). There was a small note on the page that said:

> *Desktop environment needs to support AppIndicator. Some distributions
>   (such as elementaryOS) require additional steps.

Once I installed the program by following the guide [here](https://polychromatic.app/download/ubuntu/), I was met with a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install GNOME AppIndicator by following the guide [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/re-enable-app-indicators-on-elementary-os/)